# Save multiple impala-query outputs for use in python (without saving each individual query as a .csv)

Tags: python, json, bash, dictionary, impala

I'm running multiple impala queries in a bash script, saving them to variables, printing out results in terminal, and additionally, attempting to save the output tables stored in variables to a .txt file which can then somehow be parsed in python:

```
a=$(impala-shell -q "SELECT 1;")

b=$(impala-shell -q "SELECT 2;")

echo -e "print out result of ${a}, ${b}"
```

which outputs a table like:

```
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
+---+
| 2 |
+---+
| 2 |
+---+
```

I've tried saving tables in a format that could be loaded into python as a dict with json.load:

```
import json
with open('impala_results') as f:
     data = json.load(f)
```

by doing something like:

```
echo -e "{\"a\": $a, \"b\": $b}" > /path/to/impala_results
```

to save the results, but I run in to errors no matter what I try, thinking it might be a unicode encoding issue.

```
ValueError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 152 (char 151)
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I mean, I'm not convinced this is necessarily the best way of doing things, but it would be easier to parse tables if they could be loaded in as separate and accessible objects within a dict. It's likely there's another way of doing this, if so, please let me know.

I really want to avoid saving 20+ .csv files though.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think a potential solution to this problem is to save all query results in one .csv with a custom delimiter using code similar to:

```
impala-shell -q "SELECT * FROM tbl; SELECT '~'; SELECT * FROM tbl2; SELECT '~';" -o /path/to/results.csv -B --output_delimiter=',' --print_header -o
```

then accessing it in python with:

```
with open('results.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
    results = csv_file.read()
```

and using the custom delimiter to split results into individual lists:

```
results = [i.split("\n") for i in im.split("~")]
```